# Pivot Wider table dyplr R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, aggregate, tidyverse

I have data I am pivoting and have almost perfect. The data pivoted correctly, giving me one row per my sp_BLDG and then the age and genders across the columns. I want to have a total count of each incident, but instead, I have a list in each column. Example: instead of “3” adult males at the house, I have c(“Male”, “Male”, “Male”). I think the issue is the pivot data is characters ( adult, male, female, child, etc) . The warning flags tell me  I need to use the values_, which I tried from examples in help(). Any suggestions would be great.

````
tbl_patient <- merge.all %>% 
 select(sp_BLDG, age, gender) %>%  
 pivot_wider(names_from = c("age", "gender"), values_from = c("age", "gender")) %>% 
 select(-age_Senior_Unknown, -gender_Senior_Unknown)```

Warning Messages
Warning messages:
1: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
2: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
````

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, please provide the output from `dput(merge.all)` or `dput(head(merge.all))`.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation @Limey , here is the link on github.

Comment: https://github.com/tnewton2/Rproject_tnewton2/issues/2#issue-820389211

Comment: I used this code to ouput the file

Comment: ```merge.out <- merge.all[1:30,]```

Comment: ```write.table(merge.out, file = "mergedata.txt", sep = "\t")```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I went back to the drawing board on this code. Yes pivoting is what i want to do, but that wont work with the data I have. A coworker once said to me, in order to code, you have to think like a computer.

With that in mind i basically created new columns as a binary and then summed it all up. All tools with dyplr. There's probably a shorter way to do this and i would still love to hear any suggestions.

#generate new patient table at household level

```
tbl_patient <- merge.all %>% 
filter(age != "Senior") %>% 
select(sp_BLDG, age, gender) %>% 
mutate(male_adult =ifelse(age == "Adult" & gender == "Male",1,0), male_child =ifelse(age == "Child" & gender == "Male",1,0), female_adult =ifelse(age == "Adult" & gender == "Female",1,0), female_child =ifelse(age == "Child" & gender == "Female",1,0)) %>% 
group_by(sp_BLDG) %>% 
summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)) %>% 
mutate(patient_id = seq_len(n())) %>% 
select(patient_id, everything())
```

| patient_id | sp_BLDG | male_adult | male_child | female_adult | female_child |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tc01_100001 | 8 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | tc01_100002 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | tc01_100003 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |